# Grabbing The First Character of a String

Tags: c

I am taking in a string from the stdinput via readline() a la:

```
char * cmdLine = readline();
```

Then I want to see if the first character of the string produced via readline() is an exclamation point. But the code

```
if(cmdLine[0]=="!")
```

doesn't do that for me like I would have thought. I thought that if the string snagged from stdin was "!1" for instance then it would be true that

```
cmdLine[0]=="!"
```

If cmdLine is a pointer to a string then can't I look at each character in the string with array brackets? I know this is a stupid basic c / pointer question but this is really tripping me up...

Comment: Your attempt to compare an integer (cmdLine[0]) with a pointer ("!") should have created a big fat compiler warning. If it did not, figure out how to turn the warnings on higher.

Comment: Here's another question: does your comment sound helpful? If so then you are a way better programmer than helpful person...

Comment: Yes it is helpful. Once you have the compiler warnings on, you will see these problems much sooner. That is why compilers *have* warnings.

Comment: @nbk If you want to compare the first *character* in a string, simply dereference the string (e.g. `*string`) which is equivalent to evaluating `string[0]`, e.g. `if (*string == '!')` (after you get the rest of your issues corrected) and *note:* *single-quotes* enclose a *character*, *double-quotes* enclose a *string*.

Comment: Yes, and the gcc compiler warnings are incredibly illustrative. "Comparison between pointer and integer" is really the answer I needed to tell me what was wrong. Don't be a pain the butt, dude. If you know how to answer a question just answer it. Snark is not helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `"!"` to `'!'`. You are comparing a single char to another single char.

In C you specify a char with single quotes

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have two bugs:

1. The first (less important) one is that you are comparing a char to a pointer. element11's answer addresses this point.
2. The second (more important) bug is that the warning level of your build process is too low. Fixing that is more important, because it will not only help you find bug #1, but probably a lot of other bugs as well.

How to do that depends on your compiler. When using `gcc`, the `-Wall -pedantic` options are a good start:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:16: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  if (cmdLine[0]=="!") {
                ^
test.c:7:16: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
```

Comment: Good info here. In c, undefined behavior is the last thing you want. C is often quite happy to carry on with undefined behavior as if nothing bad happened. All the while giving you output you do not expect. Having your compiler catch these is a good thing. As the size of your program grows, undefined behavior can be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

The double-quotes in `C` is used to represent an array of characters. The null-character will by default be appended to the whatever you put inside the double quotes. So

```
"!" // makes for two characters the '!' and the terminating null character '\0'.
```

Your intention clearly is to compare single character, a single character
should be enclosed in single quotes. So the right comparison would be

```
if(cmdLine[0]=='!')
```

**What happens with `cmdLine[0]=="!"`?**

As the first part of my answer says, the `"!"` makes a null terminated array of characters or a valid string. This (constant) string is stored in the data-segment part of an object file. A reference to `"x"` gives you the starting address of the string, ie you get a pointer. Hence when  you do

```
 if(cmdLine[0]=='!')
```

You're comparing an integer (mind that `char` is an integer type) with a pointer. Though this may not produce an error (this is addressed in point 2 of [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214732/1620779) answer), you will not get the intended results.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer.